# whats the different usages of interjections ちがう, いえ, いや?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, nuances, expressions, interjections

I understand the meaning of interjections   (ちがう, いえ, いや, え？, ん？,何だ？, は？). But i dont really know in what kind of situation i can use those words. Especially i would like to know the different of usages between ちがう, いえ, いや, and the differences between え？, ん？,何だ？, は,
Here i give you the examples of the conversation, i found this in "One Piece"

> シャンクス：でたな“宝払い”！お前そりゃサギだぜ
>   ルフィ：違う！！ちゃんとおれは海賊になって宝を見つけたら金を払いに来るんだ！！

The other one

> ゾロ：すぐに逃げろ。あいつらが下りてくるぜ。
>   コビー：いえ！！はっ。。。そうだあなたの縄を解かなきゃ。。。！！

other one

> 海兵１：動くな！おとなしく捕まるんだ
>   ルフィ：いやだ –

So whats the nuances and can those word being substituent for one and another?

Comment: Can ちがう, いえ, いや be used as interjections...?  Couldn't come up with examples where these words are used as such, so cannot recognize the nuances of the assumed usage..

Comment: here i give you the examples of the conversation, i found this in "one piece " 
シャンクス：でたな“宝払い”！お前そりゃサギだぜ , ルフィ: 違う！！ちゃんとおれは海賊になって宝を見つけたら金 を払いに来るんだ！！ The other one ゾロ: すぐに逃げろ。あいつらが下りてくるぜ。, コビー : いえ！！はっ。。。そうだあなたの縄を解かなき ゃ。。。！！ other one 海兵１ : 動くな！おとなしく捕まるんだ, ルフィ : いやだ –. So whats the nuances and can those word being substituent for one and another?

Comment: I believe this question is focused on ちがう, いえ, いや.  If so, could you edit the question so that we know it is focused on those 3？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ちがう, いえ, いや

As you know, these three all have the meaning of "no," if used as interjections.

First, ちがう has a stronger nuance of negation (close to "you're wrong"), compared to the others. I'm not sure if it is an interjection; ちがう can be interpreted as a complete sentence which consists of a single verb ちがう.

いえ and いや are the same in the level of negation, but politeness is different. いえ is polite and いや isn't.

---

> え？, ん？,何だ？, は？

Say "え？" when you can't understand, recognize or believe something. So this word implies that you are in doubt.

"ん？" is suitable when you noticed something. It is similar to "え？" in that you can use it when you noticed but not fully recognized something.

"何だ？" is no more than its literal meaning "What?".

"は？" can be used in the same situation as "え？" but "は？" sometimes includes the nuance of strong denial (like "I can't *understand* what the hell makes you say such a terrible thing")

Answer (score 1):

違う! means "Wrong!" Used when a companion(opponent) is saying wrong things, to become a bullish and tell it's wrong. (Polite version:違います)

いえ just means "no". Informal than いいえ.
いやだ means "I hate". Used when a companion(opponent) is trying to do that I don't hope.

Answer (score 1):

natural: "僕の財布を盗んだのは君だろう"、"いえ、違う（違います）"

a little bit unnatural: "もう昼ごはん食べたの"、"いえ、違う（違います）"

natural: "もう昼ごはん食べたの"、"いえ（まだです）"

”いえ” and "違う" is used for the denial against the speeker's message (mostly question).

"違う" is used as strong denial and the situation could be seriou.

If you are confident against your frend's suspicion. Just "いや" is natural, and this simple denial shows your confidence.

natural: "僕の財布を盗んだのは君だろう"、"いや（＝いえ）"

More examples,

natural:（子供が父に向かって）"僕のお菓子、お父さん食べた？"、（父が）"いや、食べてないよ"

natural:（子供が親友に向かって）"僕のお金盗んだだろう！"、（親友が）"違うよ！そんなことするわけないだろう"

"いや" is used among close relationship. "いえ" is rather formal.

natural: (新入社員同士の会話）"今朝遅刻したんだって？"、”いや、遅刻してないよ”

natural:（新入社員と上司の会話）"今朝遅刻したんだって？"、”いえ、遅刻していません”